# How can i make checkbox for my condtion using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, checkbox

I am trying to create checkbox list based on my condtion but i can't able to solve the problem in controller i have given two variables

```
var selectedbrand = 'Nokia';
var submodel ='Lumia';
```

based on those two variable checkbox list should change for example i have given 
selectedbrand = 'Nokia'; and var submodel ='Lumia'; for this 3 checkbox should display

```
1.Lumia 735 TS

2.Lumia 510

3.Lumia 830
```

this one should display in checkbox

```
"submodel": [
                        {
                            "price": "7500",
                            "name": "Lumia 735 TS"
                        },
                        {
                            "price": "8100",
                            "name": "Lumia 510"
                        },
                        {
                            "price": "9900",
                            "name": "Lumia 830"
                        }
                    ],
```

if i change those two variables like this

```
var selectedbrand='Nokia';

var submodel='Asha';
```

2 checkbox  should display

```
1.Asha 230

2.Asha Asn01
```

this one should display in checkbox

```
"submodel": [
                        {
                            "price": "10000",
                            "name": "Asha 230"
                        },
                        {
                            "price": "11999",
                            "name": "Asha Asn01"
                        }
                    ]
```

same thing for samsung also based on that two variables check box list should change .help me out to solve task.i have added my code below

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
var selectedbrand = 'Nokia';
var submodel ='Lumia';
    $scope.phones = [{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "56a9c44f40d0275643cfc04e"
    },
    "default": [],
    "Categories": [
        {
            "models": [
                {
                    "submodel": [
                        {
                            "price": "7500",
                            "name": "Lumia 735 TS"
                        },
                        {
                            "price": "8100",
                            "name": "Lumia 510"
                        },
                        {
                            "price": "9900",
                            "name": "Lumia 830"
                        }
                    ],
                    "name": "Lumia"
                },
                {
                    "submodel": [
                        {
                            "price": "10000",
                            "name": "Asha 230"
                        },
                        {
                            "price": "11999",
                            "name": "Asha Asn01"
                        }
                    ],
                    "name": "Asha"
                }
            ],
            "brandname": "Nokia",
            "id": "986745"
        },
        {
            "models": [
                {
                    "submodel": [
                        {
                            "price": "5000",
                            "name": "Trend 840"
                        },
                        {
                            "price": "6999",
                            "name": "A5"
                        }
                    ],
                    "name": "Galaxy"
                },
                {
                    "submodel": [
                        {
                            "price": "12000",
                            "name": "Asha 230"
                        }
                    ],
                    "name": "Asha"
                }
            ],
            "brandname": "Samsung",
            "id": "144745"
        }
    ],
    "Storename": "Zig Zag Mobiles",
    "__v": 0
}

    ]
}
```

my html code:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div class="item" ng-repeat="item in phones" ng-show="filteredEntries.length">
    {{ item.Categories.models.name }}
 <ul>
  <li ng-repeat="model in filteredEntries = (item.models | filter:{ model.name: 'Nokia'})" class="model">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="item.checked"> {{ model.submodel.name }}
  </li>
</ul>
<button ng-click="checkItems()">Do</button>
</div>  
</div>
```

i have added demo here 
[check demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/23053/)

Comment: You can have functions (scope function) for their visibility check. and on change of checkbox, you can call these functions.

Comment: i have tried my level best i can't able to solve pls help me out @Rajesh

Comment: So can you tell some logic like Why if `asha` is selected then 3rd checkbox should be hidden, in respect to data(json) that you have shared

Comment: based on this var selectedbrand = 'Nokia';
var submodel ='Lumia'; that submodel list should display in checkbox

Comment: pls add your code in fiddel @user3093073

Comment: i have updated http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/23053/

Comment: @komal Your fiddle is not showing anything, you are also using a very old AngularJS version 1.0.1

Comment: yeah i can't able to solve help me out to move forward@ chrki

Comment: You should consider mapping that data to flatter structure using more arrays than objects. No need for all that deep nesting and will simplify filtering

Comment: i am getting data from database like this @charlietfl

Comment: so?...doesn't prevent you mapping it client side

Comment: if possible we can change that object

Comment: hi @komal check this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/shailesh87/HB7LU/23058/) i hope it will give some hint

Comment: thanks@ Shailesh Singh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@user3093073, you completely misrepresent your model in your html.  I have created [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/beartums/kvrd0cb8/6/) as a starting point.  To get the data you need, you must nest ng-repeat 4 deep (phones.Categories.models.submodel) and apply your filters from that point

**UPDATE**: changes for telling the scope what submodels are selected

```
  <div class="item" ng-repeat="item in phones">
    {{ item.Storename }}
    <div ng-repeat="cat in item.Categories | filter:brandname">
      {{cat.brandname}}
      <div ng-repeat="model in cat.models | filter:submodel" class="model">
        {{model.name}}
        <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="submodel in model.submodel">
            <input type="checkbox" 
                  ng-checked="selectedItems.indexOf(submodel)>-1" 
                  ng-click="toggleSelected(submodel)"> 
            {{submodel.name}}: {{submodel.price | currency}}
          </li>

        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <button ng-click="checkItems()">Do</button>
  </div>
```

then in the controller:

```
$scope.selectedItems = [];

$scope.toggleSelected = function(submodel) {
    var idx = $scope.selectedItems.indexOf(submodel);
    if (idx==-1) $scope.selectedItems.push(submodel);
    else $scope.selectedItems.splice(idx,1);
}
```

with that functionality, you the set of selected submodels will always be available to your controller.  The only thing you need to be careful of is making sure the selected items array is cleared when you change the model.

Comment: how can i get checked checkbox values after click that button

Comment: There are a number of ways.  The quickest that comes to mind is to set a value in the controller.  I will update the answer for an option

Comment: Hmm.  What's not working?  [Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/beartums/kvrd0cb8/7/) a working fiddle.  The selected items are available in the controller as $scope.selectedItems

Comment: why that samsung is showing after that checkbox list

Comment: Error in the filter statement.  It says brandname, but should be selectedBrand (since that is what is set in the $scope).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102234/discussion-between-komal-and-beartums).

Comment: if i pass $scope.selectedlist = ["Lumia 735 TS", "Lumia 510"]; that Lumia 735 TS,  Lumia 510 checkboxs should be checked if i pass only one $scope.selectedlist = ["Lumia 735 TS"] Lumia 735 TS checkbox should be checked if i pass empty nothing should be checked

Comment: Currently, the boxes are checked based on the full object actually being in the selectedList.  So you would have to find the submodels you want and push them into the selected list.  Despite the fact that setting the checked boxes is slightly more difficult, I prefer having the whole object available when I need to do any other processing.  If you want to do it by name, then you would have to change the checked value to the name, which would be doable as well.  I'm in chat now

Comment: with name i need price also

Answer (score 0):

I think you use updated version of AngularJS but anyway see this Code :

```
<div class="item" ng-repeat="item in phones">
    <div ng-repeat="cat in item.Categories" ng-show="cat.brandname==selectedbrand">
      <h2><b>{{ cat.brandname }}</b></h2>
        <div ng-repeat="models in cat.models" ng-show="models.name==submodel">
          <h3>
            <b>{{models.name}}</b>
          </h3>
          <div ng-repeat="submodels in models.submodel">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkbox_model[$index].isChecked"/>{{ submodels.name }} 
          </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

see this link : http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/23061/

Comment: After submit I want only checked check box values.

Comment: so you find  **isChecked** value **true**  in Array and assign true value in new Array eg.

var newArray = [];
for(var item in $scope.checkbox_model){
        newArray = [];
 if($scope.checkbox_model[item].isChecked==true){
            newArray.push($scope.checkbox_model[item]);
        }
  }

Comment: can you please update your answer in fiddle .i have updated your anser but it was not working

Comment: if i pass $scope.selectedlist = ["Lumia 735 TS", "Lumia 510"]; that Lumia 735 TS, Lumia 510 checkboxs should be checked if i pass only one $scope.selectedlist = ["Lumia 735 TS"] Lumia 735 TS checkbox should be checked if i pass empty nothing should be checked

Comment: hey!!! I full fill your requirement now new code check on http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/23102/

Comment: Thanks for your help